# Method to get product price for a given customer

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-10

I need to retrieve product price via XMLRPC.

I am using Product Price Lists so each customer can be assigned a given price list which gives specific discounts based on categories, etc.

I am struggling to find which method can be used to retrieve the price for a given `product_template` id at a given quantity, if that is actually possible.

So far I have not been able to try any specific method as I can not identify how can this be achieved without actually creating a sales order.

Answer (score 1):

The module 'product' holds the pricelist mechanics. The model `product.pricelist` has a really nice method `get_product_price()`, which could be easily used server-side but not for the external/web API.

But if you have the possibility to write a little custom module, do that and override the model `product.pricelist`. Add the possibility to use this method, like:

Origin Method which can't be used because parameters are RecordSets:

```py
def get_product_price(self, product, quantity, partner, date=False, uom_id=False):
    """ For a given pricelist, return price for a given product """
    self.ensure_one()
    return self._compute_price_rule([(product, quantity, partner)], date=date, uom_id=uom_id)[product.id][0]
```

"Wrapper" for external/web API:

```py
def web_api_get_product_price(
    self, product_id, quantity, partner_id, date=False, uom_id=False):
    """ For a given pricelist, return price for a given product 
        callable from web api"""
    self.ensure_one()
    # get records
    product = self.env['product.product'].browse(product_id)
    partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(partner_id)
    # call origin method
    return self.get_product_price(
        product, quantity, partner, date=date, uom_id=uom_id)
```

Now you can call this method, an example:

```py
import xmlrpclib
db = 'db_name'
password = 'admin'
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/2/common')
uid = common.authenticate(db, 'admin', password, {})
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/2/object')
pricelist_id = 1
product_id = 5
partner_id = 7
quantity = 20
price = models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password, 'product.pricelist',
    'web_api_get_product_price',
    [[pricelist_id], product_id, quantity, partner_id], {})
```

Comment: This is very interesting thanks. I am trying this solution within next days.

Comment: How about if it is global? This will require me to fetch all product list and all that get product price method several times depending on the number of product.

Comment: What do you mean by global?

Comment: @CZoellner Apply on Global in the Create Pricelist Items

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. This methods work on every pricelist and does not depend on the types of pricelist items in it.