# External API - XML/RPC - How to get the discount price - Odoo V14

Tags: php, api, odoo, xml-rpc

For our (personal) webshop **I need to get the product discount price using the pricelist linked to a company**.

I manage to get the fixed price from a pricelist but when I change the Price Computation from "*Fixed price*" to "*Percentage (discount)*" it returns an error.

- I'm using the external API (XML-RPC) in combination with PHP.
  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/webservices/odoo.html
- Odoo 14.0+e (Enterprise Edition).

**My code:**

```
return $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $pw, 'product.pricelist', 'price_get', [['4'],84,1]);
```

When the product (ID 84) in the pricelist (ID 4) has a fixed price it returns the correct product price.

After changing the fixed price to a discount price in Odoo I get this error:

```
Array
(
    [faultCode] => 4
    [faultString] => Database fetch misses ids (('4',)) and has extra ids ((4,)), may be caused by a type incoherence in a previous request
)
```

I was looking into the Odoo code but I don't have experience using Python.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/product/models/product_pricelist.py

Comment: _may be caused by a type incoherence_ Try `[[4],84,1]` maybe

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it must be a string. When I use a int I get this error: "TypeError: dictionary key must be string"

Comment: Not all methods can be used using the Odoo API but how do I know what methods can and can't be used? The documentation is not transparent about this.

@M.E - Did you create a Odoo module to solve the problem and did it work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684565/method-to-get-product-price-for-a-given-customer?rq=1